# UPDATE FROM SELECT with foreign key on parent with one query

Tags: mysql, sql

How to update (change from first select table value second) second_table.first_table_id if first_table.email match in both select.

If it even possible. With one query!

**----------------------------------------- UPDATE -----------------------------------------**

**EXAMPLE:**

I need to update foreign key of second table if email field match in first table. I need to compare two query results with different parent_id (parents are in in same table with children)

```
         table_1
 -------------------------
| id |  parent_id | email |
 -------------------------
  1     NULL       NULL      
  2     NULL       NULL
  3      1         joe@m.ru
  4      2         bob@f.ly
  5      1         bob@f.ly
  6      2         kira@.us

     table_2
 ----------------
| id |  first_id |
 ----------------
   1       3
   2       4
   3       5
   4       6
```

1. I have two parents with ids 1 and 2 and some children (ids: 3,4,5,6).
2. Also, keep in mind: **1 - old**, **2 - new**
3. **Task**: change foreign key in second table if children email with `parent_id = 1` and chilren email with `parent_id = 2` match (are the same).
4. In our example in second table row with `id = 3` its foreign key field - first_id has to change from **5** to **4**.

Comment: I've read your question thoroughly twice and I still don't understand it. Could you please update your question to show sample data and what you expect the update to do. Oh, and "yes" I think it can be done in one query - I just don't know *exactly* what you want to do.

Comment: So the `table_2.id` column is redundant for what you need?

Comment: Did not totally understand what you meant. But table_2.id is just for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following might get you started

```
UPDATE  Table_2 t2u
SET     first_id = (
  SELECT  t2.first_id
  FROM    Table_2 t2
          INNER JOIN Table_1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.first_id
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  parent_id = MAX(parent_id), email
            FROM    Table_1
            GROUP BY
                    email
          ) t1p ON t1p.email = t1.email
          INNER JOIN Table_1 t1i ON   t1i.email = t1p.email
                                      AND t1i.parent_id = t1p.parent_id
  WHERE   t2u.first_id <> t1i.id)
```

**Test script *(SQL Server)***

```
;WITH Table_1 (id, parent_id, email) AS (
  SELECT 1, NULL, NULL      
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, NULL, NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1, 'joe@m.ru'
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 'bob@f.ly'
  UNION ALL SELECT 5, 1, 'bob@f.ly'
  UNION ALL SELECT 6, 2, 'kira@.us'
)
, Table_2 (id, first_id) AS (
    SELECT 1, 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 5
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 6
)
SELECT  t2.*, t1i.id as [update with]
FROM    Table_2 t2
        INNER JOIN Table_1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.first_id
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  parent_id = MAX(parent_id), email
          FROM    Table_1
          GROUP BY
                  email
        ) t1p ON t1p.email = t1.email
        INNER JOIN Table_1 t1i ON   t1i.email = t1p.email
                                    AND t1i.parent_id = t1p.parent_id
WHERE   t2.first_id <> t1i.id
```

**Output**

```
id          first_id    update with 
----------- ----------- -----------
3           5           4
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand that query. And I have a question. Where is in query reference for tabel_1.id = 1 (which is old) and id=2(the new). Because i need to change children with this exact ids of parents.

Comment: Is assume you mean `parent_id` and it is the `MAX(parent_id)` where it gets referenced. If you indeed mean `id`, I totally misunderstood.